# How to keep ringing sound on notification received in android even after killing app?

Tags: android, android-notifications

I have created Notification as following

```
ntent i = new Intent(this, NotificationManagerActivity.class);
    i.putExtras(bundle);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, i, 0);

    /*Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
    Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), notification);
    r.play();*/
    Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
    MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(this, notification);
    player.setLooping(true);
    player.start();

    // build notification
    Notification n = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("Amex Alert")
            .setContentText(messageDetails)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_gallery)
            .setContentIntent(pIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(false)
            .setOngoing(true)
            .addAction(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground, "More", pIntent)
            .build();



    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    if (notificationManager != null) {
        notificationManager.notify(Integer.parseInt(1, n);
    }
```

Notification rings , when I click on notification it opens the `NotificationManagerActivity`(notification Still ringing). when I kill app by swiping, notification ringing stops. But notification is still there because I have set `setOngoing(true)` (it is required). Notification ring should stop only when I stop from code . Not on killing the app.

Any Idea how to do that?

Comment: Play a sound using a service...

Comment: @Xenolion this Notification is written in service itself. You mean I have to create another separate service for playing sound?

Comment: So what do you mean by Killing the app?

Comment: @Xenolion minimizing and swiping left or right from recent apps.

Comment: May be your service is killed when that activity is destroyed! Is it a bound service that is killed when the activity is destroyed?

Comment: @Xenolion no it is started service with Service.START_STICKY. it is working if I am starting another service from notification service. but not working in notification service

Comment: Wait, what android version are you using to try this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169513/discussion-between-mky-and-xenolion).